# How do I plot x[t] vs. x'[t] (where x[t] and x'[t] are solutions to NDSolve)?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a differential equation which I solved using NDSolve. I can easily plot x[t] vs. t, x'[t] vs. t, but....

how do I plot x[t] vs. x'[t]?

I tried using the Evaluate function to simplify things, but I still have no luck.
Here's what I mean:

```
x1 = Evaluate[x'[t] /. sol];
x2 = Evaluate[x[t] /. sol];

Plot[x2, {x1, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {x[t], x'[t]}]
```

How can I plot these? 
This approach also did not work:

```
Plot[x[t]/.sol, {x'[t]/.sol, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
AxesLabel -> {x[t], x'[t]}]
```

Help!

Comment: `Evaluate` only makes sense when used inside `Plot` to distinguish the plotted functions, not during assignment.

Answer (score 10):

or from a minor modification of the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamPlot.html)

```
splot = StreamPlot[{y, -Sin[x]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3},StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]; 
Manipulate[Show[splot,
ParametricPlot[
Evaluate[
First[{x[t], y[t]} /. 
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -Sin[x[t]], 
    Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == point]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}]]], {t, 0, 
T}, PlotStyle -> Red]],
{{T, 20}, 1, 100}, {{point, {3, 0}}, Locator}, 
SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Reminds me of [Strogatz](http://books.google.com/books?id=dTvTzBeRn3cC&printsec=frontcover&dq=strogatz&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lAuUUJ3KBo-t0AG0gIFg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false). Did you ever use that book?

Comment: @rcollyer no: is it any good?

Comment: I think it is an excellent primer for undergraduates, a bit thin for graduate level work. But, it provides a nice overview so can act as a jumping off point.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for the reference! I'll look into getting a copy. I had bifurcation theory as a grad level course but somehow nothing in that made sense to me (partly I suppose because of the terrible text book we had... cant remember the name now.)

Comment: @rcollyer,@ drN this one from the doc also is particularly neat `Manipulate[Row[{Text["m"] == MatrixForm[m], StreamPlot[Evaluate[m . {x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    StreamScale -> Large, StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]}], 
 {{m, {{1, 0}, {0, 2}}}, {{{1, 0}, {0, 2}} -> "Nodal source", {{1, 1}, {0, 1}} -> "Degenerate source", 
   {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}} -> "Spiral source", {{-1, 0}, {0, -2}} -> "Nodal sink", 
   {{-1, 1}, {0, -1}} -> "Degenerate sink", {{0, 1}, {-1, -1}} -> "Spiral sink", 
   {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}} -> "Center", {{1, 0}, {0, -2}} -> "Saddle"}}]`

Comment: @drN it provides a nice foundation, primarily in the language used, so you're welcome.

Comment: @rcollyer but you can't have chaos in continuous systems with two degrees of freedom :)

Comment: @acl that is true, but the graphical techniques introduced in that book are very nice for non-chaotic systems, too.

Comment: @rcollyer The book I used was: [Elementary Stability and Bifurcation Theory](http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Bifurcation-Undergraduate-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B006WZQ84Y)

Comment: @rcollyer no of course, it was a lame joke. I've never read the book although I know the author's name somewhere

Answer (score 7):

For instance, solving this

```
sol = First@NDSolve[
   {x''[t] == Sin[x[t]],
    x[0] == 1, x'[0] \[Equal] 0},
   x,
   {t, 0, 10}]
```

and then

```
ParametricPlot[{x[t], x'[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course you can elaborate this so as to set the initial condition by clicking:

```
Manipulate[
 sol = First@NDSolve[
    {x''[t] == Sin[x[t]],
     x[0] == p[[1]], x'[0] == p[[2]]},
    x,
    {t, 0, 10}];
 ParametricPlot[
  {x[t], x'[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10},
  AxesLabel -> {"x[t]", "x'[t]"},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2*Pi}, {-2, 2}}],
 {{p, {2, 1}}, Locator}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Use `ParametricPlot`:

```
NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]

{X[u_], XD[u_]} = {x[u], x'[u]} /. First[%]

ParametricPlot[{X[t], XD[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {x[t], x'[t]}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}]
```

Comment: I just have edited (just) the formatting of your answer, because to me it looks like a very good solution to the question. One thing you might want to change is the naming of the variables which hold the solution, it usually is recommended to not use variable names which start with uppercase letters to stay out of conflicts with internal symbols.

Comment: @Albert Retey Thanks,Albert. Shall avoid starting names with capital case.(Just put in capitals so the student would relate to his own old comfy nomenclatures).

Answer (score 0):

**All the above are right and helped me too**, but I want to give you a much more *brief* and *simple* answer. 
Given a non linear equation in terms of x[t], you use:

```
solution=NDSolve[{equation,initial_cond},x[t],{t,0,10}]
```

to solve it. Then to plot x[t] vs x'[t] (phase space) you can use the following:

```
ParametricPlot[{x[t],x'[t]}/.solution,{t,0,10},AxesLabel->{x[t],x'[t]}]
```

That's it. I hope I helped you!

Comment: Welcome to our site! I was wondering what your answer adds to [the one by acl](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14028/91) which seems to give the identical solution.  In what way(s), precisely, is yours simpler?

Comment: It is the same you are right, seems like I had problems with my browser. I had some problems reading the use of NDSolve above. Sorry!