# Plotting a Phase Portrait

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to plot a [phase portrait](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PhasePortrait.html) for the differential equation 
$$x'' - (1 - x^2) x' + x = 0.5 \cos(1.1 t)\,.$$
The primes are derivatives with respect to $t$. I've reduced this second order ODE to two first order ODEs of the form $ x_1' = x_2$ and $x_2' - (1 - x_1^2) x_2 + x_1 = 0.5 \cos(1.1 t)$. Now I wish to use mathematica to plot a phase portrait. Unfortunately, I'm unsure of how to do this because of the dependence of the second equation on an explicit $t$.

Comment: Have a look at `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: you could look at this as well? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14027/how-do-i-plot-xt-vs-xt-where-xt-and-xt-are-solutions-to-ndsolve/14029#14029

Comment: Chris, this is much to complicated for me. I'm a huge mathematica newb. Could you explain more precisely?

Comment: @covertbob If you're that new to _Mathematica_, then I suggest going through some tutorials and using the virtual book. Also see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259/5) for some introductory materials. Unfortunately, this site is not the place to learn _Mathematica_ step-by-step from scratch. For starters, you can look at the code in the answer Chris linked to, and use the documentation center to read up on the functions used (e.g., `NDSolve`, `ParametricPlot`, `StreamPlot`, etc.) Just the first two should be sufficient for you to make headway on your problem.

Comment: Not an answer to your question - just a bunch of pretty phase portrait pictures - see http://drorbn.net/AcademicPensieve/Classes/12-267/QuadraticPortraits.html. The Mathematica notebook that produced the picture is linked at the bottom of that URL.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The EquationTrekker package is a great package for plotting and exploring phase space

```
<< EquationTrekker`
EquationTrekker[x''[t] - (1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] + x[t] == 0.5 Cos[1.1 t], x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

This brings up a window where you can right click on any point and it plots the trajectory starting with that initial condition:

[image]

You can do more as well, such as add parameters to your equations and see what happens to the trajectories as you vary them:

```
 EquationTrekker[x''[t] - (1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] + x[t] == a Cos[\[Omega] t],
                 x[t], {t, 0, 10}, TrekParameters -> {a -> 0.5, \[Omega] -> 1.1}
                ]
```

[image]

Comment: This no longer works in the version I have, 11.0.0.0. It produces error messages and no output. This is what has happened every time I've tried a Mathematica package. They always seem to fail in the version I am using. Sometimes I can fix the resulting errors, but usually not. In the end I always have to go back to built-in functionality, which seldom fails in my experience.

Comment: Hi, this package has a large number of errors in version 12.1 and cannot be used.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92810/equationtrekker-using-mathematica-10-2 for more about how to use EquationTrekker in versions since V10.2

Answer (score 47):

again just a slight modification from the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamPlot.html)

```
splot = StreamPlot[{y, (1 - x^2) y - x}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
Manipulate[
 Show[splot, 
  ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[
    First[{x[t], y[t]} /. 
      NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], 
        y'[t] == y[t] (1 - x[t]^2) - x[t] + 0.5 Cos[1.1 t], 
        Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == point]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}]]], {t, 0, 
    T}, PlotStyle -> Red]], {{T, 20}, 1, 100}, {{point, {3, 0}}, 
  Locator}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or just to show off (again a rip off from the documentation)

```
splot = LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{{y, (1 - x^2) y - x}, {"noise", 
     1000, 1000}}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   ColorFunction -> "BeachColors", LightingAngle -> 0, 
   LineIntegralConvolutionScale -> 3, Frame -> False];
Manipulate[
 Show[splot, 
  ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[
    First[{x[t], y[t]} /. 
      NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == y[t] (1 - x[t]^2) - x[t]+0.5 Cos[1.1 t], 
        Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == point]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}]]], {t, 0, 
    T}, PlotStyle -> White]], {{T, 20}, 1, 100}, {{point, {3, 0}}, 
  Locator}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Just a question. Is it right, that StreamPlot[{v1[x,y],v2[x,y]}] returns a set of solutions of the differential equations x'=v1; y'=v2? It looks like an elementary information that everybody knows. But it happened that I do not know, and there is no explicit discussion of this point in the Help/StreamPlot. Please let me know. Where could I have a look at the proof, or at least, an explanation? If I understand right, the StreamPlot simply yields the phase portrait, does it?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch yes it yields a set of solutions for the homogenous set of equations. But it does not attempt to be continuous. In the previous example if you remove `+ 0.5 Cos[1.1 t]` you will see that the red curve and the underlying flow become identical.

Answer (score 26):

You can solve the equation with (you might want to change the initial conditions) :

```
sol[t_] =  NDSolve[{x''[t] - (1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] + x[t] == 0.5 Cos[1.1 t], 
   x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}][[1, 1, 2]]
```

Now you can use the solution as any other function; in particular, you can plot it versus its derivative :

```
ParametricPlot[{sol[t], sol'[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]