# Phase space vector field

Tags: plotting, vector

I have a system of non linear equations and from `NDSolve` I get the solution. I plot the phase space with `ParametricPlot[{y1[t],y2[t]}/.solution,{t,0,10}]`. I want to plot the vector field and I want your help.

To be more specific, I want to see whether the fixed points are stable or unstable. I know how to do it by watching them from nonlinear dynamics, but the vector field is a much more faster way to figure out about the stability of the fixed points.

Comment: Can you post more of your work up to this point?  If you can, it will make for a much more interesting question and will likely get lots of interesting answers.

Comment: related?[http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait/14164#14164]

Comment: @chris You're right, I think it's a duplicate. Should have checked before I posted the answer.

Answer (score 4):

For an autonomous 2D system
 $$\begin{align}
y_1'(t) &= P(y_1, y_2) \cr
y_2'(t) &= Q(y_1, y_2) \cr
\end{align}$$
the phase space is the flow of the vector field $(P, Q)$.
This can be plotted with `VectorPlot` or `StreamPlot`:

```
{P, Q} = RotationMatrix[π/2].D[y2^2 - y1^3 + y1, {{y1, y2}}];
StreamPlot[{P, Q}, {y1, -2, 2}, {y2, -2, 2}]
(* P == -2 y2; Q == 1 - 3 y1^2 *)
```

[image: StreamPlot]

I'm only guessing that you have such a system, since the question did not specify.

Answer (score 2):

To show a vector field, you can use `VectorPlot` or `SreamPlot`.  You can also use the convenient EquationTrekker package to analyse the stability of a fixed point.  It has a nice GUI.

As an example let's take the following simple differential equation: $x'(t) = (1 - x(t))$.  It clearly has 1 as a stable fixed point.

With the [EquationTrekker package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/EquationTrekker/tutorial/EquationTrekker.html), you can bring up the GUI like this:

```
<< EquationTrekker`

EquationTrekker[x'[t] == (1 - x[t]), x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Then you can set several initial conditions with the mouse, and the trajectories will be automatically plotted:

[image]

I used a one-dimensional system for simplicity (= laziness), but EquationTrekker works with two-dimensonal ones as well.

With `StreamPlot` or `VectorPlot`, we can plot the vector field $\frac{d}{dt} (t, x(t)) = (1, \,x'(t))$ to find the same stable fixed point:

```
StreamPlot[{1, 1 - x}, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -1, 3}]
VectorPlot[{1, 1 - x}, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -1, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

VectorPlot will show the vector field, and StreamPlot will show the streamlines.

Comment: Suba, if you provide an example it will be more a useful answer.

Comment: Verbeia, I kind of agree. But don't you think it is really the question that dictates how specific the answer should be. I thought a generic answer would be more fitting for a generic question.

Comment: Suba, even a generic answer benefits from an example of usage of the referenced functions. I am hinting that a more expansive answer might get you more upvotes. But it's up to you.