# How can I create a phase plane?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to make a phase plane for an equation system. I want it to look something like a Mu-Space in Stat-Mech. Basically I want it to show the same system with various different initial condition pairs `{C(0), N(0)}` and show how the system evolves as an `{C[t], N[t]}` pair. I would like to have these different systems plotted on the same plane. Unfortunately I am not well equipped to deal with this sort of thing. The code I have right now is below:

```
(*Constants*)
s = .1;
g = 1;
a = .75;
p = 30;
da = .1;
alpha = .01;
beta = 1;
k = 10000;
deltaP = 10;

(*Algebraic*)
Pn = deltaP/10000;
f[t_] = 1 - 1/(a*Ca[t] + 1);
(*ODE system*)
solution = 
 NDSolve[{Ca'[t] == s*(p + Pn*Na[t])*f[t] - (g + da)*Ca[t], 
   Na'[t] == alpha + beta/k*Na[t]*(k - Na[t]), Ca[0] == 1, 
   Na[0] == 1}, {Ca, Na}, t]

Plot[Evaluate[{Na[x], Ca[x]} /. solution], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

I would like to be able to turn this code into something similar to what I described above. Any assistance is appreciated.

#### Edit

I have been trying to use Equation Trekker from the linked material. I am unsure what mistake I am making.

```
EquationTrekker[
  Ca'[t] == s*(p + Pn*Na[t])*f - (g + da)*Ca[t], 
  Na'[t] == alpha + beta/k*Na[t]*(k - Na[t]), 
  Na[t], {Ca[t], 0, 10}]
```

#### Edit2

Also, Using the parametric plot code listed in one of the responses

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{nn[t], cc[t]} /. solution], {t, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

I now have a plot of C vs N for one set of initial conditions. I don't know what the best way to get multiple such plots with different intial conditions. I have also fixed my variable names in the body of my code.

Comment: there are number of posts on this topic. For example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait  and others.

Comment: Pls check the meaning of [C](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html?q=C) and [N](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html?q=N), maybe you need to edit your code slightly.

Comment: You should not be using UpperCase letters really, but if you must, use a numbered ones, like `N0`, `C0`, etc... in addition, `N` and `C` are mathematica own symbols so using them for variables will get you in trouble very quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the constants you've given, try the following code for the solution steps

```
(*Algebraic*)
Pn = deltaP/10000;
f[t_] := 1 - 1/(a*cc[t] + 1);
(*ODE system*)
solution = First@NDSolve[
   {cc'[t] == s*(p + Pn*nn[t])*f[t] - (g + da)*cc[t],
    nn'[t] == alpha + beta/(k*nn[t]*k - nn[t]),
    cc[0] == 1,
    nn[0] == 1},
   {cc[t], nn[t]},
   {t, 0, 10}
   ]
```

This will produce two [`InterpolationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html). Note that [`C`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html) and [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) are built in Mathematica commands. One way to avoid conflicts between you own variables and built-in commands is to begin your own variable names with small letters.

Note also that when you use [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html), you have to use `cc[t]` and `nn[t]` exactly so the pattern for replacement matches the rules in `solution`.

You can do a standard plot with `t` on the horizontal axis

```
Plot[{nn[t], cc[t]} /. solution, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

And if you want a phase plot where the two variables `cc` and `nn` are plotted against each other, you can use [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html).

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{nn[t], cc[t]} /. solution], {t, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Although you can implement loops in a procedural style in Mathematica, it is generally better (eg. more efficient, cleaner code, ...) to use Mathematica's inherent [`Functional Programming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionalProgramming.html) nature.

So here you might use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) to generate a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) of multiple solutions.

```
solutions = 
  Table[NDSolve[{cc'[t] == s*(p + Pn*nn[t])*f[t] - (g + da)*cc[t], 
     nn'[t] == alpha + beta/(k*nn[t]*k - nn[t]), cc[0] == i, 
     nn[0] == j}, {cc[t], nn[t]}, {t, 0, 10}],
   {i, {1, 1.2, 1.5}},
   {j, {1, 1.2, 1.5}}
   ];
```

Then [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) this list of [`Rules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) in the first argument to [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html), which can be a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) of functions.

```
ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{nn[t], cc[t]}] /. Flatten[solutions, 2],
  {t, 0, 10}, 
  AspectRatio -> ½
  ]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Thank you. The tip regarding the 'ParametricPlot' function was very helpful. Do you have any idea what the best way to plot multiple such systems on a single plot would be (solved with different boundary conditions)? I considered simply implementing a loop, but I couldn't think of how to plot them all on a single plot in the loop. Ordinarily I use the 'Show' function when I want to combine plots. Clearly this wont work here. I also tried using EquationTrekker but could not get it to work.