# EquationTrekker using Mathematica 10.2

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, packages

I wonder whether the problem that arise with the following code is specific to my machine, as it seem to work with the documentation example.

```
Get["EquationTrekker`"]

EquationTrekker[Derivative[2][y][x] + y[x] == 1, y, {x, Pi/8, Pi}]

(* canvas is not an object with properties
"trekPane" is not an object with properties. *)
```

Comment: I have no idea what this is, but I get the same errors in MMA 10.0.0 on OSX 10.10.5.

Comment: Same thing with Mathematica 10.2 under OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: Same thing with Mathematica 11.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `PropertyValue::pvobj` messages emitted are a bug, however they do not affect the functionality. The `EquationTrekker` GUI window should still open and operate normally (I've tried it on Windows, though Linux may have further problems).

[image]

`EquationTrekker` is based on `GUIKit` which is being deprecated as far as I know, so this bug may not get a fix.

Comment: "…GUIKit which is being deprecated as far as I know…" - very sad. OTOH, this does look like something that can now be done by `Manipulate[]`; I hope someone there would consider rewriting this package.