# Plotting simple ODE system phase portrait

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am new to Mathematica, please help me to handle the following problem:

I have the following system of equations:

\begin{cases} \dot x = 2xy \\ \dot y = 1 - x^2 - y^2 \end{cases}

What I want is to draw the phase portrait in the rectangle $[-4,4]\times[-4,4]$.
This looks like the most natural thing one want to do as long as he wants to study phase portraits, since drawing them manually will take a lot of time. Unfortunately I was not able to find Mathematica code and since I am newbie I can not write it myself. I am sure this type of question is relevant for all ODE students, but I was not able to find the answer here.

Can you please help me to draw the phase portrait for this particular system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest, you study the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/) about [`StreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html).

For your example:

```
StreamPlot[{2 x*y, 1 - x^2 - y^2}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

Explanation:

```
{2 x*y, 1 - x^2 - y^2}
```

Is your ode system.

```
{x, -4, 4}
```

Is the range for your x-coord. (from -4 to 4)

```
{y, -4, 4}
```

vice versa with y.

Perhaps also interesting: [`LineIntegralConvolutionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineIntegralConvolutionPlot.html)

[Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait?rq=1)

Hope this helps.