# Phase portrait plotting

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to plot a phase portrait for the equation:

```
(d^2/dt^2)y + b * (dy/dt)^2 = A, A > 0, b < 0
```

The first thing I did was changing `dy/dt` to `p[y]`, so the equation is:

```
p'[y] + b * (p[y])^2 = A, A > 0, b < 0
```

However, when I make a stream plot and substitute for `A` and `b`, I see a blank plot. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the exact command that gives you a blank graph?

Comment: Manipulate[StreamPlot[{1, - b * (p[y])^2 + A}/. A->k /. b->m,{y,-3,3},{p,-3,3}],{k,0.1,5},{m,-5,-0.1}]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait

Answer (score 2):

You should change p[y] to p in your Manipulate-command

```
Manipulate[StreamPlot[{1, - b * (p(*[y] *))^2 + A}/. A->k /. b->m,{y,-3,3},{p,-3,3}],{k,0.1,5},{m,-5,-0.1}]
```