# Phase Portrait for ODE with IVP

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to make a phase portrait for the ODE x'' + 16x = 0, with initial conditions x[0]=-1 & x'[0]=0. I know how to solve the ODE and find the integration constants; the solution comes out to be x(t) = -cos(4t) and x'(t) = 4sin(4t). But I don't know how to make a phase portrait out of it. I've looked at this link [Plotting a Phase Portrait](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait) 
but I couldn't replicate mine based off of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Phase portrait for any second order autonomous ODE can be found as follows.

Convert the ODE to state space. This results in 2 first order ODE's. Then call `StreamPlot` with these 2 equations.

Let the state variables be $x_1=x,x_2=x'(t)$, then taking derivatives w.r.t time gives $x'{_1}=x_2,x'{_2}=x''(t)=-16 x_1$. Now, using `StreamPlot` gives

```
    StreamPlot[{x2, -16 x1}, {x1, -2, 2}, {x2, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To see the line that passes through the initial conditions $x_1(0)=1,x_2(0)=0.1$, add the option `StreamPoints`

```
StreamPlot[{x2, -16 x1}, {x1, -2, 2}, {x2, -5, 5}, 
 StreamPoints -> {{{{1, .1}, Red}, Automatic}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To verify the above is the correct phase plot, you can do

```
ClearAll[x, t]
ode = x''[t] + 16 x[t] == 0;
ic = {x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1/10};
sol = x[t] /. First@(DSolve[{ode, ic}, x[t], t]);
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{sol, D[sol, t]}], {t, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The advatage of phase plot, is that one does not have to solve the ODE first (so it works for nonlinear hard to solve ODE's).

All what you have to do is convert the ODE to state space and use function like `StreamPlot`

If you want to automate the part of converting the ODE to state space, you can also use Mathematica for that.  Simply use `StateSpaceModel` and just read of the equations.

```
eq = x''[t] + 16 x[t] == 0;
ss = StateSpaceModel[{eq}, {{x[t], 0}, {x'[t], 0}}, {}, {x[t]}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above shows the `A` matrix in $x'=Ax$. So first row reads $x_1'(t)=x_2$ and second row reads $x'_2(t)=-16 x_1$

**Update to answer comment**

The following can be done to automate plotting  `StreamPlot` directly from the state space `ss` result

```
A = First@Normal[ss];
vars = {x1, x2}; (*state space variables*)
eqs = A . vars;
StreamPlot[eqs, {x1, -2, 2}, {x2, -5, 5}, 
 StreamPoints -> {{{{1, .1}, Red}, Automatic}}]
```

Comment: Can you method  plot `y''[x]+2 y'[x]+3 y[x]==2 x`?

Comment: @yode Phase portrait are used for homogeneous ode's. Systems of the form $x'=A x$ and not $x'=A x + u$. Since it shows the behaviour of the system itself, independent of any forcing functions (the stuff on the RHS).  This behavior is given by phase portrait diagram. The reason is, it is only the $A$ matrix eigenvalues and eigenvectors that determines this behaviour, and $A$ depends only on the system itself, without any external input being there.

Comment: Can we plot your `ss` in MMA directly?

Comment: @yoda Yes. I've updated the above with what I think you are asking for. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

`EquationTrekker` works for me, but if you are not interested in looking at a range of solutions, it might be easier to just do it with `ParametricPlot`

```
x[t_] := -Cos[4 t]

ParametricPlot[{x[t], x'[t]} // Evaluate, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
 Axes -> False, PlotLabel -> PhaseTrajectory, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {x[t], x'[t]}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: What version is this on, Bill? Someone in the QA that OP links to says `EquationTrekker` is broken for them on v11.0

Comment: This plot is from `ParametricPlot`, not `EquationTrekker`, but in v12.0 `EquationTrekker` gives me plots, although I do get PropertyValue errors.