# How to Generate a Phase Portrait for a Jacobian Evaluated at Fixed Points

Tags: plotting, difference-equations

Consider the following: The Jacobian matrix J given below correctly generates the eigenvalues for the (x,y) fixed point shown below. When looking at the stability of the fixed point the absolute values of the eigenvalues of J are needed. In this case, the eigenvalues are complex and hence the absolute value is the complex conjugate of the two eigenvalues. All this too is correctly computed. Since the complex conjugate of these two eigenvalues is less than one, it follows the fixed point is stable.

How would a Phase Portrait or the Mathematica function Stream be used to show that the ABSOLUTE VALUE of the eigenvalues of J show stability since their complex conjugate is such that both eigenvalues are less than unity?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
(*Jacobian Matrix J, Evaluated at Fixed Point x = (1-b)/p, y = c(p+b-1)/(p*(1-b+c))*)
f1={(1-p*y)*x+c*(1-x-y),(p*x+b)*y};
f2={x,y};
J=Grad[f1,f2]//MatrixForm
(*Jacobian Evaluated at the Fixed Point x = (1-b)/p, y = c(p+b-1)/(p*(1-b+c))*)
J=Grad[f1,f2]/.{x->(1-b)/p,y->c (p+b-1)/(p*(1-b+c))}//MatrixForm
J=Grad[f1,f2]/.{x->(1-b)/p,y->c (p+b-1)/(p*(1-b+c))};
Eigenvalues[J]//MatrixForm
Eigenvalues[J]/.{p->0.8,b->0.5,c->0.01}
Abs[%]
Eigenvectors[J]/.{p->0.8,b->0.5,c->0.01}
```

Here is the difference equation that produced the above fixed points.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
x0=0.90;y0=0.10;z0=0;p=0.8;b=0.5;c=0.01;
{tmin,tmax}={0,25};
N[TableForm[MapThread[Prepend,{RecurrenceTable[{x[t+1]==(1-p*y[t])*x[t]+c*(1-x[t]-y[t]),
y[t+1]==(p*x[t]+b)*y[t],z[t+1]==(1-c)*z[t]+(1-b)*y[t],x[0]==x0,y[0]==y0,z[0]==z0},{x,y,z},{t,tmin,tmax}],Range[tmin,tmax]}],TableHeadings->{None,{"t","x[t]","y[t]","z[t]"}}]]
```

Comment: Are you thinking of a differential equation or a difference equation?

Comment: it's actually a difference equation

Comment: I just added it the code (below the first part of code). I'm interested in the phase portrait of x and y; don't need z.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait?rq=1) ?

Comment: I don't want to use Equation Trekker. Appreciate you  pointing it out but it doesn't meet my needs. I'm working with discrete dynamical systems not a single or continuous equation (not differential equations). Mine are difference or recurrence equations.

Comment: For difference equations, you can build phase space using a set of initial conditions (select initials and iterate). Since you know fixed points, just select initials near them.

Comment: @PRG Your system is 3D in (x,y,z) space and it depends on 6 parameters `x0,y0,z0,p,b,c`. Why do you use 2D subspace to compute Jacobian?

Comment: The x[t+1} and y[t+1] equations are independent of z[t+1]; hence, I'm just interested in the phase portrait of x and y. For this reason, you could remove the z[t+1] equation from the code above and then just consider the x[t+1] and y[t+1] as a 2x2 system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Discrete System:

$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}&=c \left(1-(x_n+y_n)\right)+x_n \left(1-p y_n\right)\\
y_{n+1}&=\left(p x_n+b\right)y_n
\end{align}
$$

The Discrete System code:

```
F[{x_, y_}, {b_, c_, p_}] := Evaluate[{(1 - p*y)*x + c*(1 - x - y), (p*x + b)*y}]
MatrixForm@(F[X, μ])
X = {x, y};
μ = {b, c, p};
```

The Jacobian Matrix:

```
J[{x_, y_}, {b_, c_, p_}] := Evaluate@D[F[X, μ], {X}]
MatrixForm@(J[X, μ])
```

The fixed points:

```
X1[{b_, c_, p_}] = Simplify@SolveValues[F[X, μ] - X == 0, X][[1]];
X2[{b_, c_, p_}] = Simplify@SolveValues[F[X, μ] - X == 0, X][[2]];
MatrixForm@X1[μ]
MatrixForm@X2[μ]
```

Linear approximations:

```
J1[{b_, c_, p_}] := Evaluate[FullSimplify@J[X1, μ]]
J2[{b_, c_, p_}] := Evaluate[FullSimplify@J[X2, μ]]
MatrixForm[J1[μ]]
J2[{b_, c_, p_}] := Evaluate[FullSimplify@J[X2, μ]]
MatrixForm[J1[μ]]
```

Conditions on the parameters to study the stability of the fixed points:

Local stability of the fixed point $X_{1}$:

```
Reduce[Tr[J1[μ]] - 1 < Det[J1[μ]] < 1 && Variables[J1[μ]] > 0](*locally stable*)
(*Conditions on system parameters*)
Reduce[1 < Det[J1[μ]] < Tr[J1[μ]] - 1 && Variables[J1[μ]] > 0](*locally unstable*)
(*False*)
```

Local stability of the fixed point $X_{2}$:

```
Reduce[Tr[J2[μ]] - 1 < Det[J2[μ]] < 1 && Variables[J2[μ]] > 0](*locally stable*)
(*Conditions on system parameters*)
Reduce[1 < Det[J2[μ]] < Tr[J2[μ]] - 1 && Variables[J2[μ]] > 0](*locally unstable*)
(*Conditions on system parameters*)
```

Stability test for $X_{1}$ with $b=1/2$, $c=1/100$ and $p=8/10$:

```
μ0 = {1/2, 1/100, 8/10};
Det[J1[μ0]]
Det[J1[μ0]] < 1
Tr[J2[μ0]] - 1 < Det[J2[μ0]] < 1 (*Stability*)
(*16781/17000*)
(*True*)
(*True*)
```

Stability test for $X_{2}$ with $b=1/2$, $c=1/100$ and $p=8/10$:

```
μ0 = {1/2, 1/100, 8/10};
Det[J2[μ0]]
Det[J2[μ0]] < 1
Tr[J2[μ0]] - 1 < Det[J2[μ0]] < 1 (*Stability*)
(*1287/1000*)
(*False*)
(*False*)
```

Time Series and Phase Portrait:

Using `RecurrenceTable`:

```
data = With[{b = 1/2, c = 1/100, p = 8/10, X0 = {1, 3/10}}, 
RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == (1 - p*y[n])*x[n] + c*(1 - x[n] - y[n]), 
y[n + 1] == (p*x[n] + b)*y[n], {x[0], y[0]} == {X0[[1]], X0[[2]]}}, {x, y}, 
{n, 1, 1300}]];
```

Time Series:

```
ListPlot[data[[All, 1]], Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 0.9}}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
ListPlot[data[[All, 2]], Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 0.065}}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Time Series]

Phase Portrait:

```
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, 
PlotRange -> {All, {-0.005, 0.11}}, PlotStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Phase Portrait]

An additional code:

```
PhasePortrait[data_, linap_, fp_, range_, style_] := Module[{stcond, plot}, 
stcond[linap2_, fp2_] = Piecewise[{{Graphics[List[PointSize[0.012], Lighter[Blue], 
Point[fp]]], Tr[linap] - 1 < Det[linap] < 1}, {Graphics[
List[{PointSize[0.012], Black, Point[fp]}, {PointSize[0.006], 
     White, Point[fp]}]], 1 < Det[linap] < Tr[linap] - 1}}]; 
plot = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> range, PlotStyle -> style, 
Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 1, 
ImageSize -> Medium];
Return[Show[plot, stcond[linap, fp]]]]
(*We can improve this code, PRG!*)
```

Note: If $\text{det}(J(X_{0}))=1$, the fixed point $X_{0}$ can be stable or unstable and, along with other conditions, it can be a Neimark-Sacker bifurcation.

Test:

```
PhasePortrait[data, J1[μ0], X1[μ0], {All, {-0.005, 0.11}}, Black]
```

`I hope you enjoy it!`

Comment: E. Chan-López: Amazingly creative!! ... truly clever ... many thank you's ... as a teacher sharing knowledge like this is admirable and this contributes so well to student learning ... v/r ... @prg

Comment: @prg I appreciate your assessment on this small contribution. I consider sharing to be a feedback process.

Answer (score 10):

First, we can plot phase portrait for 3D system as follows (see comment @I.M.)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
x0 = 0.90; y0 = 0.10; z0 = 0; p = 0.8; b = 0.5; c = 0.01; Do[
 lst[i] = RecurrenceTable[{x[t + 1] == (1 - p*y[t])*x[t] + 
       c*(1 - x[t] - y[t]), y[t + 1] == (p*x[t] + b)*y[t], 
     z[t + 1] == (1 - c)*z[t] + (1 - b)*y[t], 
     x[0] == x0 (1 + .1 RandomReal[{-1, 1}]), 
     y[0] == y0 (1 + .1 RandomReal[{-1, 1}]), 
     z[0] == z0 (1 + .1 RandomReal[{-1, 1}])}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 
     1000}];, {i, 20}]

ListPointPlot3D[Table[lst[i], {i, 20}], PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Note, we also can drop first 100-200 points in every `list[i]` to make it more clear

```
ListPointPlot3D[Table[Drop[lst[i], 100], {i, 20}], PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

We can make projection on XY plane by dropping `z` from `lst[i]`, we have

```
Do[lst2[i] = Table[Drop[lst[i][[j]], -1], {j, Length[lst[i]]}];, {i, 
  20}]

ListPlot[Table[Drop[lst2[i], 100], {i, 20}], PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]
```

[image: Figure 3]

System has two stationary points, we can compute as

```
eq = {x[t + 1] == (1 - p*y[t])*x[t] + c*(1 - x[t] - y[t]), 
   y[t + 1] == (p*x[t] + b)*y[t], 
   z[t + 1] == (1 - c)*z[t] + (1 - b)*y[t]};
s = NSolve[
  eq /. {x[t + 1] -> x[t], y[t + 1] -> y[t], z[t + 1] -> z[t]}, {x[t],
    y[t], z[t]}]

Out[]= {{x[t] -> 1., y[t] -> 0., z[t] -> 0.}, {x[t] -> 0.625, 
  y[t] -> 0.00735294, z[t] -> 0.367647}}
```

Only last of them is stable. The question is how we can show stability of this point? Theorem states (see Theorem 4 [here](http://m6auer.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M6/Lehrstuhl/MatBio1_201011WS/discrete_dynamics.pdf)): Let $u_{n+1} = f(u_n)$ be an autonomous system. Let J be the Jacobian matrix of f, evaluated at v. Then

1. v is asymptotically stable if all eigenvalues of J have magnitude less than 1.
2. v is unstable if at least one eigenvalue of J has magnitude greater than 1.

Let check our two cases.

```
J = Table[Grad[eq[[i, 2]], {x[t], y[t], z[t]}], {i, 3}]

Out[]= {{0.99 - 0.8 y[t], -0.01 - 0.8 x[t], 0}, {0.8 y[t], 
  0.5 + 0.8 x[t], 0}, {0, 0.5, 0.99}}

 Eigenvalues[J /. s[[1]]]

Out[]= {1.3, 0.99, 0.99}

 Eigenvalues[J /. s[[2]]]

Out[]= {0.992059 + 0.0541935 I, 0.992059 - 0.0541935 I, 0.99 + 0. I}

 Abs[%]

Out[]= {0.993538, 0.993538, 0.99}
```

Therefore the first stationary point is unstable and the last one is stable.

Comment: Alex: Very clever -- beautiful ...How might I use StreamPlot to show this for just the x[t+1] and y[t+1] only?

Comment: @PRG See update to my answer.

Comment: `PlotTheme -> "Marketing"` is a nice touch ;)

Comment: @ChrisK We understand what marketing is. :)

Comment: For a more general local stability analysis, apply the Jury's test, considering all the parameters involved as free (it is similar to Routh-Hurwitz).

Answer (score 3):

Of course trajectories are not continuous in discrete-time, so `StreamPlot` isn't totally relevant.  See [this blog post](http://phaseportrait.blogspot.com/2013/01/discrete-time-phase-portraits.html) for some related discussion.

Instead, why not plot a grid of arrows, showing the action of `f1`?

```
f1 = {(1 - p*y)*x + c*(1 - x - y), (p*x + b)*y};
p = 0.8; b = 0.5; c = 0.01;

Show[Graphics[Table[
  If[{0, -1} \[VectorLess] f1 \[VectorLess] {1, 1}, Arrowheads[0.015], Arrow[{{x, y}, f1}]}]
, {x, 0.05, 0.95, 0.05}, {y, -0.9, 0.9, 0.1}]],
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

That's kind of busy, but if we zoom in to the equilibrium it will look better:

```
arrows = Show[Graphics[Table[
  If[{0.55, 0} \[VectorLess] f1 \[VectorLess] {0.7, 0.015}, {Arrowheads[0.015], Arrow[{{x, y}, f1}]}]
, {x, 0.555, 0.695, 0.005}, {y, 0.0005, 0.0145, 0.0005}]],
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0.55, 0.7}, {0, 0.015}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Now add isoclines and a trajectory to see the stability:

```
isoclines = ContourPlot[Evaluate[Thread[f1 == {x, y}]], {x, 0.55, 0.7}, {y, 0, 0.015}];

sol = RecurrenceTable[{
  x[t + 1] == (1 - p*y[t])*x[t] + c*(1 - x[t] - y[t]),
  y[t + 1] == (p*x[t] + b)*y[t], 
  x[0] == 0.56, y[0] == 0.004}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1000}];
trajectory = ListPlot[sol, PlotStyle -> Pink, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All];

Show[isoclines, arrows, trajectory]
```

[image]

Comment: Not working for me; what is VectorLess? I'm running ver 11.1

Comment: Hmm, introduced in v12.0 I see.  For a VectorLess-less version, just do `arrows = Show[Graphics[Table[f1, {Arrowheads[0.015], Arrow[{{x, y}, f1}]}, {x, 0.555, 0.695, 0.005}, {y, 0.0005, 0.0145, 0.0005}]],  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0.55, 0.7}, {0, 0.015}}, AspectRatio -> 1]`.  It will be slightly uglier, but no big deal.

Comment: Hi Chris: Sorry but in ver 11.1 I'm getting the error "Table is not a Graphics primitive or directive".

Comment: Oops, should have been `arrows = Show[Graphics[Table[{Arrowheads[0.015], Arrow[{{x, y}, f1}]}, {x, 0.555, 0.695, 0.005}, {y, 0.0005, 0.0145, 0.0005}]], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0.55, 0.7}, {0, 0.015}}, AspectRatio -> 1]` -- sorry!

Comment: Chris: That works! ... many thanks for sharing your skills in insights!

Comment: @ChrisK Very nice (+1). Please pay attention that model is 3D not 2D.

Comment: To Both Chris and Alex: My sincere thanks to you two for sharing your talents and insights. I appreciate your willingness to share with so many of us on Mathematica learning curves!!