# Van der Pol's equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, homework, differentials

Consider the van der Pol equation below:
(x′′)+c(x^2−1)(x′)+(x)=0 , which governs
the flow of current in a vacuum tube with three internal elements. It can be written as
the system
x′= y , y′= -x-c(x^2 - 1).y
By setting c = 2/3, x(0) = 1 and y(0) = 0,

i need  to :

1. find x(1) and y(1).

2)graph the solution that satisfies these initial conditions,
i) x(t) and y(t),
ii) x(t) versus y(t)

3)present a version of the previous graph with control added to allow interactive
manipulation of the value of c. Observe and explain the results.

Comment: Similar to [14160](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait).

Comment: Please add to your question the Mathematica code you have tried and describe the problems you have encountered.

Comment: Probably it can all be done with [`EquationTrekker`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/EquationTrekker/ref/EquationTrekker.html).  Be sure to look under "Options" > "TrekParameters" to see how to input the parameter `c`.

Comment: Oops, I meant the [tutorial for `EquationTrekker`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/EquationTrekker/tutorial/EquationTrekker.html).

Comment: when you say you need to find `x(1) and y(1).` did you mean `x(t) and y(t)` instead?

Answer (score 2):

A phase space plot of the homogeneous Van Der Pole equation is easily obtained. E.g.:

```
tmax = 15;
Manipulate[
 eq = {x''[t] + c (x[t]^2 - 1) x'[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, 
   x'[0] == 0};
 f[t_] = x[t] /. NDSolve[eq, x[t], {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
 ParametricPlot[{f[t], f'[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]
 , {c, 0., 1}, TrackedSymbols :> {c}]
```

[image]

The rest you should be able to figure out yourself.